# Application Startup checks, where should I perform them in the MVVM pattern?

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, startup

I would like to start up a C# / WPF / MVVM Application with an instance of my Main View Model after checking a local file for database connection settings.

Once I have the connection settings I will bind them to a class and include them in my Main View Model.

I'm thinking that I would check the local file and create the instances of the Main View Model, and Main Window in App.xaml.cs

Any thoughts ? Is there a better way to do this ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I usually do just what you said: create the initial View and ViewModel in `App.xaml.cs`

```
protected override void OnStartup(StartupEventArgs e)
{
    base.OnStartup(e);

    var vm = new MainViewModel();
    // set vm properties

    var view = new MainView();
    view.DataContext = vm;

    view.Show();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You could implement this responsibility in a separate class that is responsible for navigation (loading (a ViewModel and) a View and listening for navigation messages).

In the App class you would only have to instantiate and initialize this class.